# Pandas Dataframe - apply filter to rows

Tags: python, pandas

Could anyone please let me know if there is a better way to apply filter to row in a pandas dataframe.

I am running following code to check if what is the difference between 1st row and 2nd row and also, a function would return True or False if there is a different.

```py
        data = [
            (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
            (10, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100)
            ]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "f", "g"])
        df.loc['diff'] = df.iloc[1]-df.iloc[0]
        df_1 = (df.loc["diff"] != 0).to_frame("result")
        df_2 = df_1.loc[df_1["result"] != 0]
        print(df_2.size)
```

Comment: Do you need the number of `True` values or the column names for those?

Comment: I need the actual difference as I store that to excel and I need to return status to my code if there is difference or not

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2D intermediates to slice, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) directly:

```
df_1 = df.loc[:, df.loc["diff"]!=0]
```

You don't even need multiple slicing, just create the desired output directly:

```
df_2 = df.loc['diff', df.loc['diff']!=0].to_frame('result')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this if you just want a one-liner:

```
data = [
            (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
            (10, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100)
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "f", "g"])

result_df= pd.DataFrame(df.nunique()>1).loc[pd.DataFrame(df.nunique()>1)[0]==True]
```

Basically "`df.nunique()>1`" finds the number of unique values in each row. You want the columns where that count is greater than 1.

"`pd.DataFrame(df.nunique()>2)`" puts the boolean results into dataframe and "`.loc[pd.DataFrame(df.nunique()>2)[0]==True]`" filters out to where a difference (True) is reported.

I ran it in Jupyter labs and this was the result:
[image]